# Users are not able to login laravel website due to redis error is occured. when restart redis service then this error is not coming

Tags: mysql, laravel, redis

My application has three different servers which is implemented in Laravel:-
1. Cron server
2. Mysql server 
3. User server

Laravel version - 5.6
PHP version - 7.1
Operating system - Centos

After 1-2 days when I am trying to login into website then following error had occoured:-

ERROR: MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error. {"exception":"[object] (Predis\Response\ServerException(code: 0): MISCONF Redis is configured to save RDB snapshots, but is currently not able to persist on disk. Commands that may modify the data set are disabled. Please check Redis logs for details about the error. at /var/www/html/vendor/predis/predis/src/Client.php:370)

When I restart the service of redis then I am able to login again.

What is its best solution??

I had tried to solved this issue with following steps:-
1. Dir - set the permission 755 of this directory
2. -- redis-cli 
   -- config set stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no 
   -- sudo systemctl restart redis

Following errors are occured time to time in redis logs:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please reply on this

Comment: I am noticed that after some time 'dir' path is automatically changed. Firstly when I check "dir" path by this command "CONFIG GET dir" then its showing this path "/tmp". When I restarted the service of redis and again check the "dir" path then its showing this path "/var/lib/redis". Could you please explain me why "dir" path is changed automatically????